# Recharts ReferenceLine between data points

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a Recharts `LineChart` with numeric x-Axis. I would like to draw a `ReferenceLine` on an arbitrary x-value, but if the x property of `ReferenceLine` is not any of the x values in my data, it is not showing.

with

```
const data = [{ x: 1, y: 3 }, { x: 1.5, y: 4 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }];
...
<ReferenceLine x={1.7} stroke="green" label="actual" alwaysShow={true} />
```

nothing is showing, where as

```
const data = [{ x: 1, y: 3 }, { x: 1.5, y: 4 }, { x: 2, y: 3 }];
...
<ReferenceLine x={1.5} stroke="green" label="actual" alwaysShow={true} />
```

works.

I have built the sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-playground-xxwnl

Is there a way to make the ReferenceLine show for every x?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was that I had not explicitly set the XAxis type to number. After changing

```
<XAxis dataKey="x" />
```

this to

```
<XAxis type="number" dataKey="x" />
```

it's behaving as expected

Comment: Is this weirdness mentioned in the docs _anywhere_!?